# neural genes expressed in nasopharyngeal specimens

Tags: human-biology

Is it possible in a nasopharyngeal specimen genes of neural system to be expressed? For example, genes about neural differentiation?

Comment: Can you please add some more details? Of course there can be some genes that are expressed in two different tissues. If you provide a background to your question then it would be a bit more clear.

Comment: I mean if it is possible to find genes that are specific for neural development and differientation in pharyngeal cells.

Answer (score 1):

This paper mentions using a cytology brush (not the usual NP swab) to obtain cells from the olfactory epithelium. They obtained and cultured neural precursor cells. Have a look.

Trends in molecular medicine.

"The Olfactory Neural Epithelium as a Tool in Neuroscience"

Joëlle Lavoie, Patricia Gassó Astorga, [...], and Koko Ishizuka

from:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5399677/